# Guice Multi-binding Injection in javax.validation.ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, guice, check-constraints

I want to use Guice Multibinding injection in javax.validation.ConstraintValidator.

Not getting any clue to inject map binder in my ConstraintValidator class.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `MapBinder` in the following way, it does it's job, but I need to refactor to make it better.  To give you some background,  I had to match a legacy program for copying data from a primary database to any number of subsequent databases using a combination of files (don't ask, but it works).  Anyhow, I use a super simple mapping scheme of `TableName -> TableTransferHandler`, here is how I define the bindings:

```
MapBinder<String, TableTransferHandler<?>> binder 
    = MapBinder.newMapBinder(
        binder(), 
        new TypeLiteral<String>() {}, 
        new TypeLiteral<TableTransferHandler<?>>(){});

// Add my Table handlers based on table name.
binder.addBinding("table_one").to(TableOneTransferHandlerImpl.class);
binder.addBinding("table_two").to(TableTwoTransferHandlerImpl.class);
```

which gets used as such:

```
@Inject
Map<String,TableTransferHandler<?>> handlers;

TableTransferHandler<?> handler = handlers.get(tableName);
handler.process();
```

It's very trivial, and needs to be rewritten, but for the most part it gets the job done.  From what you've explained though, I'm not sure if you want `MapBinder`, you probably want to return the regular binding for a `ConstraintValidator`.  If I had chosen to implement a `TableTransferHandler` by remote system, instead of by name, I would have done this:

```
Multibinder<TableTransferHandler<UserAccess>> binder 
    = Multibinder.newSetBinder(
        binder(), 
        new TypeLiteral<TableTransferHandler<UserAccess>>() {});
// Add all my remote handlers relating to UserAccess
binder.addBinding().to(RemoteOneUserAccessTableHandler.class);
binder.addBinding().to(RemoteTwoUserAccessTableHandler.class);
```

Which would then be used:

```
@Inject
Set<TableTransferHandler<UserAccess>> handlers;
for (TableTransferHandler<UserAccess> handler : handlers) {
    handler.process();
}
```